# Who governed London during the Great Plague?

Tags: england, government, 17th-century, london

I am writing a story for a game and I want to try to make it as accurate as possible. To this end, I would like to find who governed London, England, during the time of the Great Plague, but I can't seem to find it. So, who governed London during the Great Plague?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to have this covered; [City of London Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London_Corporation) and [Great Plague of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Plague_of_London).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The day-to-day running of London remained in the hands of the [Lord Mayor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Mayor_of_London). This from the [National Archives](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/education/resources/great-plague/):

> The Lord Mayor and aldermen (town councillors) remained to enforce the
>   King’s orders to try and stop the spread of the disease. The poorest
>   people remained in London with the rats and those people who had the
>   plague. Watchmen locked and kept guard over infected houses. Parish
>   officials provided food.

The [poster](http://www.bl.uk/learning/histcitizen/uk/plague/gov/localgov.html) below is from 1646 but the orders therein are almost identical to the those of 1665.

[image: Orders by the Lord Mayor]
*Source: http://www.bl.uk/learning/images/uk/plague/large3333.html*

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Plague_of_London#Exodus_from_the_city), it was the Privy Council (formal advisors to the king) which took the decision to start [household quarantines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Plague_of_London#Exodus_from_the_city).  Once the plague was out of control (July), King Charles II moved to Oxford, which was where [Parliament](https://www.britannica.com/event/Great-Plague-of-London) was held. Others who could also left London, including [lawyers, merchants and doctors](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/education/resources/great-plague/) (!).